# Qt Creator autocomplete: Enable mid-string matching

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qt-creator

Qt Creator has an autocomplete/intellisense feature, but it matches only identifiers that strictly start with what you have typed:

For example, if I have a member called `ui->label_4`, and I start typing `ui->label`, it would get listed, but if I try typing `ui->_4` or `ui->l_4`, it would not, because even though `_4` is part of the identifier, it does not start with it.

Example:

[image]

Is there a way to enable mid-string matching in Qt Creator autocomplete? I looked everywhere in the options but I couldn't find anything.

My current version is Qt Creator 2.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm getting the mid-string matching behavior by default in Qt Creator 3.0.  I don't recall ever seeing that behavior in prior versions of Qt Creator.

[image]

Comment: You're right, I had misunderstood how it works, because I had tried with a 3-word variable at first - for example `sevenEightNine`, and it wouldn't work for `sevennine`, because you need to type at least one character of the second word before it will match for the third. So I assumed it just doesn't work, lol.